# So easy to close a question, so hard to reopen it? Is this an issue?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Close/Reopen Votes - Sliding Scale For Threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/close-reopen-votes-sliding-scale-for-threshold)
>   [Notify on edit of a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-on-edit-of-a-closed-question)

A [question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89265/follow-up-on-your-new-questions-minutes-after-posting-them-do-you-agree) got closed today. Too quickly I may say. ([See another related meta question of mine here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89293/do-users-understand-the-clear-disinction-between-noise-or-pointless-and-not-a)).  I took measures to repair the issue and voted to reopen it. And now I am in a waiting... waiting... mode. (Well not physcially).  Isn't this ironic that a question gets closed so quickly and reopening it seems like a big hassle where I have to wait on some other people to take action and I don't know how long it takes.. if ever!?

While my original plan was to wait for a few days before posting this, I deciced I am not patient enough and it's just a tip (the original question) for others' benefit.

On a side note, do closers get a notification when a reopen request has been submitted?

Comment: Do we have a standard place to link users to when they really don't get things? Like a "So you've decided to make incorrect assumptions about how Stack Overflow works" pamphlet? It would just save so much time explaining things.

Comment: @Vamp - somebody should compile a list of inquiries that are posed with some regularity. I realize that's a mouthful, so we'll abbreviated it "ITAPWSR". We'll make it a link at the top of each page.

Comment: @status, I obviously am not talking about the FAQ. That's more for specific "How do I close a question?" type things. I mean something about the fundamental spirit of the hit-and-run nature of questions and answers, which strikes me as what Tony doesn't get.

Comment: Some @Vampire obviously sucked the sense of humor out of Welbog.

Comment: It was my Master Jeff Atwood.

Comment: I saw that coming (I am a psychic, you know).

Comment: I can tell because I used echolocation to locate your psychosis.

Comment: I'm sorry but despite your efforts to add several question marks, there doesn't really seem to be a question again.  What is it?

Comment: I'll give you that one, @vamp, but I'm saving a "you suck" comment for later.

Comment: I'm a bat, man.

Comment: You're batty. I'll give you that, @vamp.

Comment: I'd have seen what you did there if I weren't so blind.

Comment: Oh the irony...

Answer (score 2):

It might be an issue, in some cases, on the "real" sites. Your [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89265/follow-up-on-your-new-questions-minutes-after-posting-them-do-you-agree)'s on meta, though, and it feels strange talking about it here (will you post a follow-up if this question gets closed?). It'd be more useful to point to an example from SO, a site I see that you ask a lot of questions on.

To answer your question, though:

- There's not a lot of follow-up on closed questions. It's a bit of a problem, and makes hash of our arguments against reposting questions (*"just edit your question, and it'll get reopened!"* - not so much). Some tools might be helpful (*show questions that were edited after being closed*).
- Your referenced question should not be reopened. Adding a question mark to a rant does not make it into a valid question.

Comment: "will you post a follow-up if this question gets closed?" let's find out!