# Say 'edit pending' instead of nothing when an edit is pending and user rep < 2000

Tags: feature-request, edits

When an edit is pending and the user rep is less than 2000, currently it shows nothing i.e. just `link | flag` with 'edit' removed.

Instead, to help remove confusion, show non-linked 'edit pending' instead of 'edit'.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't propose this before.  +1.