# FAQ: Migrations

Tags: support, migration, moderators, migrated-questions

What are the rules on migrations:

1. Migrations in general
2. Migrations to public betas
3. Migrations to private betas

Comment: Yes, I know this isn't the proper format yet ... I want to know if this is a dupe, I don't think so ... since "migration [faq]" doesn't return any particularly relevant results.

Comment: Should probably be rolled into http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance or the topic should be split from that one into this separate one.

Comment: @AdamDavis You know I'll chat about it ;) but this is intended for moderator level (I figured tagging it as such would be the best way to handle that, rather than putting some huge block in the Q, but maybe I should) because there's a tool for migrating them (of course you know that) that is not the same as the general close dialog, and we need it to be spelled out not only now, but in the future for new mods as well. So I don't mind if they are merged/split, but I don't know what of that Q belongs with this Q properly. Also, 1) above could just link there?

Comment: Well, the rules are the same for moderators and users - it's just that regular users have fewer choices for migration.  So I'd suggest one topic that covers both mods and users, even though users would really only be subject to 1) above, and that in a limited fashion (5 most commonly migrated to sites only).  But, you know, I'm not offering to do the work, so go ahead and do it however you feel is best.  I'm just offering an opinion that may well be the wrong tactic to choose for moderator faq questions.  In fact, now might be a good time to introduce the faq-moderating tag, or similar...

Comment: Well that's just it (and of course it's not public knowledge of a regular matter) but we've been getting _directed_ as moderators as a group to start putting this stuff on meta, and that it's ok that it be targeted to mod's alone. We've been arguing for a more localized site, but we are pretty sure the dev team is gonna kick our teeth in if we keep it up ;) ... so yeah, this is intended to be for mods for faq, and normally you're right, except that as you can see from what I've got below, there's no way for "regular users" to control out-of-band migrations. However, they can still flag so ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Migrations in general
2. Migrations to public betas

   - Betas may not survive. Unless a beta seems particularly strong, or unless a question is just *absolutely* certifiably oriented for that site, then the question should not be migrated.
   - Remember that a site may still receive questions from sister sites during the beta period, but that process should be considered and not *just willy nilly*.
3. Migrations to private betas

   - Don't migrate to a private beta. The beta might not survive that long. Give it time to get its legs under it.

Collected thoughts:

1.

> Jeff Atwood: "Don't migrate crap. Clean it up instead. If the question can't be salvaged, or is a complete dupe, close it."

2.

> Jeff Atwood: "Don't migrate known duplicates. Close it instead."

3.

> Gilles: Migrate to X only if you think of X as “us” and “we want it on our site”