# Tag cleanup/burninate: amazon-ec2 and amazon-web-services

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I'd like to get the community opinion on a suggested tag cleanup / burninate.

These two tags seem to attract a lot of questions that should really belong on ServerFault:

1. [amazon-ec2](/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2)
2. [amazon-web-services](/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services)

Just looking at the first ten questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2, most of them look like they belong on ServerFault.

Really the only StackOverflow questions that should use those tags relate to API usage. But, like I said, I'm seeing lots of questions that don't belong. The question comes down to: cleanup or burninate?

Comment: Why is this question voted negative? It seems a legitimate question.  Even if the community disagrees with the proposal, should it really get negative votes?

Comment: @JBCP Meta votes express (dis)agreement. See [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree.

There is a very valid set of questions that revolves around one or both of the following:

1. Using the Amazon AWS APIs (including the EC2 API)
2. Software development tools and development-type questions on using the Amazon infrastructure.

both of which are on-topic for SO.

We do unfortunately get a good number of OT questions that are related to administering the service or general Q&A; those are off-topic but we have a mechanism for dealing with those now.

Answer (score 3):

[This has been discussed recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f).

Essentially, as I lay out in my `Faq-Proposed` post, these questions should go through the [same litmus test we send all other migrations through](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150276/what-are-the-guidelines-for-migrating-posts/150277#150277).

We should not just arbitrarily send all questions with a particular tag to Server Fault.  If the question isn't reasonably expected to get new answers or to enrich the target community in some meaningful way, then it's just shifting bits around for the sake of pedantry.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a mass migration, by the way.

Comment: @SimpleCoder Oh, good.