# Require moderators to get agreement with target site moderators for migration actions

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-tools

I recently came over [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188742/is-it-possible-to-multitask-neopixels-in-arduino) where the decision to migrate it from [SE Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) to [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) was obviously wrong, as that question doesn't fit for the target site policies.

I don't know how moderators communicate over cross site boundaries, but I'm sure that such migration action should be reviewed and confirmed by the target site moderators and go there in first place.

Comment: I would expect the general *don't migrate crap* would apply here. I'm not sure if we need a feature / process for something that is probably a missclick. Maybe ping the mod: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/359501/timeline

Comment: @rene If there's such policy already (and _crap_ actually applies there IMO), I'm just fine with it. The mod was pinged already by me, but the comment is removed now.

Comment: I think push-pull of questions between communities' review queues could work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186461/215590

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, the standard recommendation to the moderators (from the CMs) is specifically [to **not** ask a site mod before migrating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119115/377214):

> You don't need permission to migrate questions, and definitely shouldn't be pinging moderators on another site every time you have something that needs migration.

While mods are an easy source of knowledge about a site, they're not the all-knowing, final deciders of site scope; the users are. As such, rejecting the migration can be done by any five users closing the question *for any reason* (duplicates will stay but be marked as duplicates). There's really no reason to get another moderator involved. [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) explains the process for migration [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212271/284336).

That said, like with any migration, the rule for moderators and regular users alike is "[Don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/284336)" and we generally *hope* that our fellow mods will at least look at the site guidance before migrating, particularly when trying to send something to a site they're unfamiliar with... but it's really not a big deal. But, if a question looks on topic and doesn't look like a horrible question, there's no real reason to wait on migrating it to get a response from a site mod on the target site.

Occasionally I've seen (and have done myself) that mods on a site will come and report in to the migrating moderator to let them know if a the question was a bad fit for the site, particularly when several questions were migrated that were bad fits... but clearing every migration before sending is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

Just close and/or delete the question, or if you're not a mod/high rep user flag the post with the "other" option explaining the problem. That'll reject the migration.

If it keeps happening then the site mods can ping the other site's mods in TL to remind them to be careful when migrating that a) the question isn't just a bad question and b) it's actually on topic on the target site.

All mods *should* take the view that if there's any doubt about a migration then don't do it.

Comment: I'm of too low rep there (SECR) to propose deletion, otherwise I would have done so be sure.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - ah. I assumed you were a mod/high rep user - sorry. In that case flag the post using the "other" option. One of the mods will do the needful.

Comment: _"In that case flag the post ..."_ That's what I did of course. But such mistakes should be prevented beforehand IMO, that's why I put this FR.