# How to move a question from stackoverflow.com to other website?

Tags: discussion, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Migrate a Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question)
>   [Closing/Migrating question instructions/guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance)

I asked a question on stackoverflow.com, but now I feel that it would be more appropriate if this question was present on serverfault.com.

Is there anyway I can move this question, or may be notify a moderator of doing so?

I think flagging the question is probably a way of achieving this. But would my flagging (that is, flag by the user who asked the question) would alone be enough to move the question?

Or, is it like that the flag of the user who asked the question is given no extra weightage and treated the same as of other users? This thing will actually make a difference in the time involved in moving the question.

Any suggestions anyone?

TIA.

Comment: @Bobby: Thanks for sharing the link Bobby. But after going through the link, I could not make out an answer for the thing I have asked here. Could you guide at the thing asked in the question above?

Comment: [Ok, take this instead.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question)