# How (not why) do I migrate a question to another site as a moderator?

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions, guidelines

I've read the guidance on why and when I should migrate a question. It's pretty obvious when, and certainly when not to (if there's any doubt). But the guide doesn't tell me how I should do to migrate questions.

> The guide: [Closing/Migrating question instructions/guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance)

The guide I need is a step-by-step action list which I haven't found yet, such as:

1. On the question, select the *mod* link
2. In the options given, select *migrate to* option
3. Select the site to migrate to in the editable drop down control
4. When you select *OK* the receiving site need to accept your migration suggestion before it's performed.

Or something like that. Is this guide available?

## Edit

Following the guide by random♦ I see no option to select any other site, nor to search for a site.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the question:

1. Click **close**
2. Select **Off topic because...**
3. Select **This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**
4. Select **belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**

   Or place your cursor into the text field that has **type to search**
5. Type in the name of the site (or its domain/subdomain) you want to migrate to.

   Matching sites will appear.
6. Select the site that matches and that you want to send over to.

   The name will fill inside the text field.
7. Click **Vote to Close**

#### But

This option is not available if:

- the question was already migrated from another site or
- it is [older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

Comment: Thanks! But where I mod (SharePoint.SE) this option isn't available AFAIK. See my updated question with the screenshot.

Comment: @Benny Then the question might not be eligible for migration. You can (even as a mod) only migrate a question that is less than 60 days old.

Comment: @animuson That's it! Thanks a lot! It's been bugging me since November last year :-)

Comment: If the question has been already closed by the community, should I reopen it first? Is there a way to avoid this?